# Terraform error with dynamic block in for_each

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to instantiate an azure storage_share map using the azuremrm resource [storage_share](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/storage_share.html). By design, I need to be able to instantiate more than one storage share with the same block; each of those shares may or may not have an "acl" section.

I was thinking of solving this issue using a for_each in conjuction with a dynamic block, as in the related SE question:

Main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_storage_share" "storage_share" {
  for_each             = var.storage_share_map
  name                 = each.key
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  quota                = each.value.quota

  dynamic "acl" {
    for_each = each.value.acl
    content {
      id = acl.value.id

      access_policy {
        permissions = acl.value.access_policy.permissions
        start       = acl.value.access_policy.start
        expiry      = acl.value.access_policy.expiry
      }
    }
  }
```

The variable would be defined as:

```
variable "storage_share_map" {
  type = map(object({
    quota = number,
    acl = object({
      id = string,
      access_policy = object({
        expiry      = string,
        permissions = string,
        start       = string
      })
    }),
  }))
  default     = {}
}
```

and later parametrized in my tests as:

```
storage_share_map = { 
  my-share-2 = {
    quota = 123,
    acl = {
      id = "a-id",
      access_policy = {
        expiry      = "ISO8061 UTC TIME"
        permissions = "rwdl"
        start       = "ISO8601 UTC TIME"
      },
    },
  }
```

However, when testing, terraform returns the following output:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on .terraform\modules\sa\main.tf line 83, in resource "azurerm_storage_share" "storage_share":
  83:       id = acl.value.id
    |----------------
    | acl.value is object with 3 attributes

This object does not have an attribute named "id".


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on .terraform\modules\sa\main.tf line 83, in resource "azurerm_storage_share" "storage_share":
  83:       id = acl.value.id
    |----------------
    | acl.value is "a-id"

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on .terraform\modules\sa\main.tf line 86, in resource "azurerm_storage_share" "storage_share":
  86:         permissions = acl.value.access_policy.permissions
    |----------------
    | acl.value is object with 3 attributes

This object does not have an attribute named "access_policy".


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on .terraform\modules\sa\main.tf line 86, in resource "azurerm_storage_share" "storage_share":
  86:         permissions = acl.value.access_policy.permissions
    |----------------
    | acl.value is "a-id"

This value does not have any attributes.
```

As I understand it, the issue here is that the for_each inside the dynamic block is either malformed or misbehaving: acl.value appears to be both valued as the string "a-id" and carrying three attribute (?).

**Terraform** version 0.12.26
**Azurerm** version 2.26.0

Any insight would be appreciated.

**Related question:**
[Dynamic block with for_each inside a resource created with a for_each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57890909/dynamic-block-with-for-each-inside-a-resource-created-with-a-for-each)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By iterating in the dynamic block with `for_each = each.value.acl`, you are iterating over the values in the `object` type. It appears you really want to iterate over the `acl` themselves. You would need to adjust your type to:

```
variable "storage_share_map" {
  type = map(object({
    quota = number,
    acl = list(object({
      ...
    }))
  })),
}
```

You can tell from the error messages that currently it is iterating over `id` and then `access_policy`, and failing to find the two requested attributes for each, which is why you have 2*2=4 errors.

You can adjust your input correspondingly to:

```
storage_share_map = { 
  my-share-2 = {
    quota = 123,
    acl = [{
      id = "a-id",
      access_policy = {
        expiry      = "ISO8061 UTC TIME"
        permissions = "rwdl"
        start       = "ISO8601 UTC TIME"
      },
    }],
  }
```

and this will achieve the behavior you desire.

Note that Terraform 0.12 has issues sometimes with nested object type specifications, so omitting the `acl` with `[]` may result in crashing under certain circumstances.

Comment: Yea, I ended up using your solution before reading it. Seems more stable; I'm painfully aware of the bugs

Answer (score 4):

Please use square brackets for `each.value.acl`.

Azure storage share block should look like:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_share" "storage_share" {
  for_each             = var.storage_share_map
  name                 = each.key
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.sa.name
  quota                = each.value.quota

  dynamic "acl" {
    for_each = [each.value.acl]
    content {
      id = acl.value.id

      access_policy {
        permissions = acl.value.access_policy.permissions
        start       = acl.value.access_policy.start
        expiry      = acl.value.access_policy.expiry
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tinkered with your solution for a bit, but I encountered an issue with the way terraform manages the list. I ended up developing Matt Schuchard's proposed answer on my own ;)

Comment: I think that this answer is a little confusing.  In this answer - you are creating a new array with only the `each.value.acl` value in it.  Pushing the set or map into the variable documents the behavior cleaner.